# Counter is updated only once despite clicks

Tags: jquery, ajax, live

I'm trying to build a counter where the admin user of the web site may update a counter by clicking a link. When the user clicks the counter link $.get sends the data to a mySQL record and the record is updated. The number is then sent back to Jquery which updates the counter without refreshing. Up to this point everything works.

The problem happens when the user clicks more than once. The MySQL record is updated correctly but the counter is updated only the first time the user clicks the link. Here's my code:

```
<div class='counter' id='4592'><a href=''>Counter: 24</a></div>

$.get("jquery.php", { id: $(this).attr('id'), counter: 'increase' }, 
    function(data) {
        $('.counter').replaceWith('<div class="counter" id="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"><a href="">Counter: ' + data + '</a></div>');
    }
);
```

PHP:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$num = $_GET['counter'];


switch ($num) {
    case 'increase':
        // ---- Before updating the record get the number saved in the database
        $qry = mysql_query("SELECT counter FROM table WHERE id='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
        $number = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
        $n = $number['counter'];

        // ---- Increase the counter and update the record
        $a = $n + 1;
        mysql_query("UPDATE table SET counter = '".$a."' WHERE id = '".$id."'");

        // --- Send data back
        echo "Counter: ".$a;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the page you're testing?

Comment: The web site is under development locally. I need to set it up. I need some time.

Answer (score 2):

`$.get` requests are cached by default, so every subsequent request is not actually goes to the server. Use `$.ajax` request passing `cache: false` as a parameter or use `ajaxSetup` to turn off caching globally.

Comment: As explained below to Kamaci I did tried ajaxSetup to turn off cache but it did not work. By the way, every click is correctly passed to the server and the counter is correctly updated. I can tell this because if I refresh the page the counter number is displayed correctly. I mean, I click 3 times, Jquery updates only once but the dB is updated 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Few queries -
1. $(this).attr('id') does it work on the callback. Are you getting the correct id ?
2. Replace with replaces the content. Why are you adding the div again to counter ?
3. This should work fine :-

```
$('.counter').replaceWith('<a href="">Counter: ' + data + '</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should setup the defaults of your $.get jquery method for cache:

```
$.get = function(url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        async : false,
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: callback,
        cache: true
    });
};
```

The other method is using that:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache : true}); 
$.get(...);
$.ajaxSetup({cache : false});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion to set `$.ajaxSetup({cache : false});` as first statement after `$(document).ready(function($)` but it did not change anything.

Comment: I did delete the browser's cache but nothing changed.